# converting a dataframe command to worksheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Blessings,

I cannot save using df commands because it overwrites my xlsx file

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpg7P.png]

While wb does this correctly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku9jm.png]

What needs to be done is convert this command into something similar using ws

```
df = df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(), na=False), keep_columns]
```

What this does is look within the dataframe for anything in the 'IDC S/N' column that contains args.num.lower (input) and fiters output using only certain columns (keep_columns)

If anyone knows how to do this your help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: pandas are not able to do any adjustments in the existing excel file tables and for that task openpyxl or xlsxwriter is used, in quite similar manner as Excel VBA macros, with last row variables and etc.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: sorry, mate, I have no experience with xlswriter or openpyxl, 
but check their documentation about filters, like https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_autofilters.html 
it most likely will lead you towards solution or googlesearch keywords

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the input, the process, and the expected output? Is it a wb processed by pandas that you want to save as a different wb? Sample data would be nice.